How to send a parameter to a GnuRadio block from C++ using UDP?
I am trying to send the frequency value of the GR "Signal Source" block from an external C++ code, using UDP.
So far I can send UDP packets (as arrays of bytes) to GR from my C++ code, but I don't know how to extract the value for the frequency and how to pass it to Signal Source input. If I understood correctly, the parameter "frequency" is a GnuRadio message type, so I need to convert the byte(s) I send with UDP into a GR message, but I am not 100% sure if this is correct and how to do it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

The UDP source is the wrong block to use here; instead, you could use the "ZMQ REQ Message Source", and get a message connection right away.
Then, on your external code, use zeromq instead of UDP (it's easier, or at least not harder, I promise). There's zeromq bindings for any major programming language these days. You'll want to put a serialized PMT message into that sending socket.

Thank you, I'm looking into this. When I use the ZMQ REQ Message Source block and connect its output to 'Frequency' (input of Signal Source block) I get the error: Param 'Frequency' Expression None is invalid for type 'real'.

then you will need to change the format of the PMT you're sending in! https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Signal_Source#Message_Ports explains how you can build such a cmd dict.

I think I'm getting there. I used a Message Strobe and cmd dict (since freq is deprecated) to test this and it worked, i.e. the frequency changed. I just need to figure out how to give the value from ZMQ REQ block now, and then send a ZMQ message from C++ with the frequency value

I missed the serialization part. Does ZMQ offer any tools/functions to do it (I didn't find it) or do I need to use something else, like Google Buffers?

it's built in to ZMQ; functionality is called serialize
